# Where can I find iOS dual display for Apple TV documentation?

Tags: ios, ipad

Would anyone know the whereabouts of the documentation on how to implement AirPlay dual-screen functionality into an app?

e.g. http://www.apple.com/uk/appletv/airplay/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html) has very brief, but from what I can see totally sufficient information if you scroll down to "Make the Most of a Second Display".

In short, you register for notifications on a connect to an external display to get a handle to it, and switch between drawing on the two displays by using setScreen(). Besides that, everything drawing related should be "the usual".

Answer (score 0):

> Overview
> The user can connect additional screens to an iOS device at any time using AirPlay or a physical cable. Each additional screen represents new space on which to display your app’s content, and is managed by a UIScreen object. For example, a game might show its content on a connected display and show game controls on the iPhone screen, as illustrated in Figure 1. [Displaying Content on a Connected Screen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_content_on_a_connected_screen)